# EmberJS Action target an object within an array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Given the following jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EasyCo/KTmKh/5/

I figured this to be pretty straight forward but I'm stuggling.

I have an object, in the object I have a property that is an array of objects with properties.

```
// Create an instance
var drt = window.App.TowelObj.create({
    name: "Dry Towel",
    availableIn: [
        {
        color: "red",
        size: "small"},
    {
        color: "blue",
        size: "medium"}
    ],
    wetness: 0,
    isEditing: true
});
```

I loop through the array and list out the property values.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="towels">

{{#each availableIn}}
    <div>
        <a {{action doStuff target="controller" context="color"}}>{{color}}</a>
    </div>
{{/each}}

</script>
```

When somebody clicks the property value, I just want to be able to update it to whatever. For example, when they click on the color I want the color property value to update to say... purple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'll have to answer my own question on this one. As @peter-wagenet and @bradley-priest suggested, I did need to make use of the ability to send a context using the action helper.

This used in conjunction with `{{#each item in list}}` I can set the context to the specific object being viewed.

I also had to create Ember.Object(s) for the availableIn array of objects so that I could use the .set method.

So without further ado, here's my working solution. If you have a better solution, I'd be more then happy to see it.

Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application">
    <h1>If you're gonna survive out here, you've got to know where your towel is.</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="towel">
    <h2>The availableIn:</h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="towels">

{{#each item in availableIn}}
    <div>
        {{! The default click action will find the controller and look for doStuff and send it the event with the context set to item }}
        <a {{action doStuff item target="controller"}}>{{item.color}}</a>
    </div>
{{/each}}

</script>
```

Javascript

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
        this.initialize();
    }
});

window.App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                var controller = router.get('applicationController');
                controller.connectOutlet('towel');
                controller = router.get('towelController');
                controller.connectOutlet('towels');
            }
        })
    })
});

window.App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
});

window.App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();

window.App.TowelController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();

window.App.TowelView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'towel'
});

// Towel Object model
window.App.Towel = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: null,
    availableIn: [],
    wetness: 0,
    isEditing: false
});

// Style Object model
window.App.Style = Ember.Object.extend({
    color: null,
    size: null
});

// Create some style instances
var style1 = window.App.Style.create({
    color: "red",
    size: "small"
});

var style2 = window.App.Style.create({
    color: "blue",
    size: "medium"
});

// Create a towel instance
var drt = window.App.Towel.create({
    name: "Dry Towel",
    availableIn: [style1, style2],
    wetness: 0,
    isEditing: true
});

// The Towels Controller
window.App.TowelsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    // Set the content to our dummy data
    content: drt,

    // Define the action doStuff
    doStuff: function(event) {

        // Grab the context which is the object being cliked and change it's color property to 'purple'
        event.context.set('color', 'purple');         
    }
});

// The Towels View
window.App.TowelsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'towels'
});​
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EasyCo/cE2xP/

Comment: This answer help me. My requirement was to invoke a method of the item in a loop(target="item"). Here goes the example.

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="towels">

{{#each item in availableIn}}
    <div>
        {{! The default click action will find the controller and look for doStuff and send it the event with the context set to item }}
        <a {{action doStuff item target="item"}}>{{item.color}}</a>
    </div>
{{/each}}

</script>

Answer (score 4):

So close, you must be referring to out of date documentation.
The action helper now takes an optional third (or more) parameter/s as a context.

```
<a {{action doStuff color target="controller"}}>{{color}}</a>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/4EyB8/

Comment: Close but not quite. I want to change the actual clicked property. For example, if you click `red` I want to update the object property `color` for that specific clicked on object property.

Comment: I basically want to achieve what I did here with a CollectionView: http://jsfiddle.net/EasyCo/KTmKh/2/  

But that's an undesirable way to do it since I'm manipulating the object in the view which is a mix of concerns.

Comment: I think you just want to replace `color` with `this`, `{{action doStuff this target="controller"}}`. Alternatively, use the `{{#each item in list}}` syntax to avoid ambiguity.